# Resistivity of heating element

Tags: electrical-resistance

My book says that heating elements of appliances such as an electric heater should be made up of alloys because alloys have higher resistivity (AKA specific resistance) than their constituent metals. It says that this would allow the heating element to generate more heat.
What i don't understand is: If the resistance is high, and the voltage (across the main supply) is constant:

$$\mathrm{Heat} = \frac{V^2t}{R}$$

As $R$ is more, the heat produced should be less.

So, why must it be made up of an alloy? alloys provide a higher resistance. This would cause the amount of heat generated to be lower than the amount of heat generated if a metal was used.

Comment: Sounds like you've nearly rediscovered the [maximum power transfer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem): For greatest heating, the resistivity of the load should equal that of the source.

Answer (score 1):

The advice you have read is either wrong or situational.

If an (ideal) power source has infinitely low output impedance, then the lower the heater resistance, the more heat will be generated, as your formula predicts.

However, a real power source will have a specific output impedance $Z_O$, so at some point (when the heater resistance becomes too low) it will not be able to source the necessary current. To generate the maximum power with a resistive heating element, it must have a specific resistance of
$$R=Z_O$$
Alloying a heater element can help tuning the resistance to this specific value, but one could also change the length or cross-section of the heater wire to achieve the same. In the end, the heater material is chosen to be compliant with the thermal and environmental conditions, and not primarily to tune the resistance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of practicality, not a law.

The power dissipated in the heating element is given by $P=I^2R$. Hence, to supply the same power to a lower-resistance element, you need more current. As we reduce the resistance of the heater ($R_h$) it becomes a question of whether the supply is able to generate enough current to give us the required power.

That in turn depends on the design of the supply and also, as @tobalt said, on the internal resistance $R_i$of the supply. If the heater resistance were the same as that of the supply, i.e. if $R_i=R_h$, then half the power would be dissipated in the supply - which probably is not desirable!

The higher the supply voltage, the higher $R_h$ should be for the same power. As most heaters run from a 220V or 110V supply that dictates the required resistance. Usually, the easiest way to achieve that resistance is with a short high-resistivity wire, not a very long low-resistivity wire.

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot more sense to me now

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the power dissipated is $V^2/R$ and thus if the voltage $V$ is fixed by being the mains voltage the only control that you have is the value of the resistance $R$ of the heating element.

Nichrome is an alloy which is often used in heating elements and it has a resistivity $66$ times larger than that of copper.
So for a given diameter of wire to have the same resistance a copper wire would have to be $66$ times longer than a nichrome wire or for given length of wire to have the same resistance a copper wire would have to be a diameter $\sqrt 66 \approx 8$ smaller than a nichrome wire.
Using the increased length option would make it difficult to package the copper wire into a heating element and using decreased diameter option would make the copper wire more susceptible to being damaged.

Another important point is that Nichrome and other resistance alloys are much more resistant to oxidation than copper.

Thus the statement, *It says that this would allow the heating element to generate more heat*, is misleading.

Comment: Thanks for your response